# Python - why is regular expression much more efficient than search in list?

Tags: python, regex

When I had a look at the **Google Code Jam Qualification Round 2009 problem**: [**Alien Language**](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/90101/dashboard), the plain idea is that you generate all possible strings from the pattern, and hold it in a list, then test and count matched strings. This algorithm is simple, straight-forward, but it consumes incredibly large RAM and your laptop undoubtedly die.

Another way to solve this problem is to substitute `"()"` with `"[]"` for use of regular expression. Python embedded `re.match()` and `string.replace()` took less than a few seconds to pass the large test. Now the question, why is regular expression much more powerful??

In my understanding, there could be certain mechanism like `yield` function that enables you to generate a "generator" - iterable, and one-pass. But it's my guess.

Comment: Searching via regexp does not require generating all the possible strings that could match the regexp.. is that the crux of your question?

Comment: @AndrewMagee how is it implemented? Documents like https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html# didn't explain.

Comment: The idea of DFA will be helpful here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton

Comment: I have met DFA before but never made a thought about regular expression could be implemented in this way. I believed it was merely some formalization tool which has no use in practice. Wrong. Well, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is largely correct.

For the computer science details, you can look up the ideas of "[nondeterministic finite automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton)" and "[deterministic finite automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton)".

You can think of a regexp compiler as something that takes a regexp and produces a *function* which operates on your input string and keeps a state, which it updates as it consumes the input string based on rules derived from the regexp.

Hopefully I'm not butchering things too much if I say that conceptually,  a regexp of, say, `(ab|cd)` would produce something that behaves like this:

```
def match_ab_or_cd(s):
    state = "start"
    for c in s:
        if state == "start":
            if c == "a":
                state = "state_a"
            elif c == "c":
                state = "state_c"
        elif state == "state_a":
            if c == "b":
                return True
            elif c == "a":
                state = "state_a"
            else:
                state = "start"
        elif state == "state_c":
            if c == "d":
                return True
            elif c == "c":
                state = "state_c"
            else:
                state = "start"
    return False


>>> match_ab_or_cd("ab")
True
>>> match_ab_or_cd("cd")
True
>>> match_ab_or_cd("ae")
False
>>> match_ab_or_cd("aaaaab")
True
```

So for many simple regexes it's possible to produce a machine that only needs to consume each character in the input string once. Bear in mind though that there are regexes that do not play nicely, such as [`(x+x+)+y`](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regex-performance/).

Oh and here's [a fun tool that visualises how regular expressions turn into state machines](http://hackingoff.com/compilers/regular-expression-to-nfa-dfa). You can think of the first picture it produces as an intermediate step, and the second picture is what can be translated into a machine like the above.